# How to add style in GeoServer with restsharp

Tags: c#, style, geoserver-rest-api

I can add new style application/zip with Postman into GeoServer,  but I can't do it with  C#-RestSharp.
How can I do this?

```
      string url = "http://" + server + "/geoserver/rest/styles?name="+ StyleName;

            var client = new RestClient(url);
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            string authInfo = username + ":" + password;
            request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authInfo)));
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/zip");
            request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy");
            FileStream uploadFileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"D:\aa.zip");
            request.AddParameter("application /zip", uploadFileStream, ParameterType.RequestBody);
              
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

---

```
   string url = "http://..../geoserver/rest/styles?name=" + StyleName;
   wsn = "mystyle";

   WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

   request.ContentType = "application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml";
   request.Method = "POST";
   string authInfo = username + ":" + password;
   request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + 
   Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authInfo));
   request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
   byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(wsn);
   Stream reqstr = request.GetRequestStream();
   reqstr.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
   reqstr.Close();
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add more information to your question, we need to know what does or does not happen, what the log file shows when you try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = new RestRequest("/styles");
request.Method = Method.POST;
request.AddParameter("styleBody", YOUR_SLD_STYLE_WHERE, "application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml", ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml");
var response = _restClient.Execute(request);
```

I don't know if you still have the problem, but it might help someone... I decided to put the style as a requestParameter and not as a body and not as a zip file.